# Literacy rate of Rokugani

Tags: lore, languages, l5r, rokugan, culture

Rokugan is a setting taking heavy influence from the '80s and '90s perception of *medieval* Japan (through a north-American lens) and strewing in influences from other East-Asian countries, creating the unique mashup fantasy world.

I know the core rulebooks stress that almost all Samurai are able to read and write the Rokugani script (which is pretty much Chinese/Japanese-expy), but I fail to find references for literacy rates in the general populous outside of the Samurai caste.

Merchants appear likely to be literate, but do the books give a ratio of literacy or if there is a general line? Like, can craftsmen, farmers, or people handling butchery read and write?

Answer (score 4):

I can find this quote from p.215 of 4e Emerald Empire:
"all Rokugani samurai can read and write (unlike some heimin and most eta)"

I can't find where it's written at the moment but I seem to recall that peasant literacy changes depending on where you are. The highest literacy rate would be in Phoenix lands as they take care of their peasant's spiritual and academic interests. The lowest would be among those in Scorpion lands as the Scorpion generally give their peasants only the bare minimum attention.